# return-to-libc exploit : where to provide arguments for system() call?

Tags: security, unix, calling-convention, shellcode

I am trying to write a return to libc exploit, but am not able to figure out where in stack should I place the argument for my `system()` call.

The vulnerable function is

```
void func(char *str)
{
     char buffer[12];
     strcpy(buffer,str);
}
```

The stack for this function will look something like this:

```
 -----------
 str
 -----------
 return address
 -----------
 previous frame pointer
 -----------
 buffer
 -----------
```

I understand that I must overwrite the return address with the address for `system()` call, but where should I place the address for its arguments and why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer to the argument should be found immediately above the return address. That is, after the overwrite, your stack should look something like this:

```
-----------
shellcode: /bin/whatever ...
...
...
...
\0
-----------
&shellcode    <-- str is here
-----------
&system       <-- return address is here
-----------
previous frame pointer <--- don't corrupt this
-----------
padding       <-- buffer
```

Note that this implies you must know what `%esp` is when you reach `strcpy` (to avoid corrupting the previous frame pointer). Also, none of the pointers can contain a zero byte.